# JavaFX Replace new Text with old one without overwriting it in the scene

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am pretty new to Java and in the second month of my training.
I want that every time I press <kbd>New</kbd>, the old text deletes and then the new one comes. But it doesn't work. I have already made research on the Internet.

When I press <kbd>New</kbd>, the new text comes over the old text. I thought that if I make `text(null)` before, it deletes it. But it doesn't work.

After pressing the button more times:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
buttonNew.setOnAction(ae -> {
    int randomM1 = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
    int randomM2 = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
    System.out.println(randomM1 + " x " + randomM2);
    System.out.println(randomM1 * randomM2);
    
    Text mText = new Text();
    mText.setText(null);
    mText.setText(randomM1 + " x " + randomM2);
    rootM.getChildren().add(mText);
    mText.setLayoutX(300);
    mText.setLayoutY(200);
    mText.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 50));
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a new `Text` on every button click, and adding this new `Text` into `rootM` every time.

When you say `mText.setText(null);` you are clearing the text of the newly created `mText` variable, which is different from the one already added to the layout.

To overcome this, you can define the `Text` variable once outside the event handler, and just update its text when needed.

```java
final Text mText = new Text();
rootM.getChildren().add(mText);
mText.setLayoutX(300);
mText.setLayoutY(200);
mText.setFont(Font.font("Verdana",50));

buttonNew.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // your code to generate random ...

        mText.setText(randomM1 + " x " + randomM2);
    }
});
```